# Stange behavior of time in @react-native-community/datetimepicker IOS device

Tags: ios, react-native, timepicker

I am having a very strange issue in the IOS device for @react-native-community/datetimepicker while using "TIME" mode.

Whenever I change the time it automatically reverted back to the actual time, time reset on changing. Can you please guide how I can fix this issue?

**NOTE: ITS ONLY HAVING ISSUE WITH IOS DEVICES.**

> Attach is the link to the snack so that you can check quickly.

https://snack.expo.dev/@dedevelopers/date-time-picker-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the `date` you need to update the current date in the DatePicker in the `onChange` callback function like this:

```
  const onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
    const currentDate = selectedDate;
    setDate(new Date(selectedDate));
   ....
}
```

You can check this fixed snack based on yours :D from [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@louay12/date-time-picker-issue)